# Pyramid global object share across thread

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a small pyramid web service.

I have also a python class that creates an index of items and methods to search fast across them. Something like:

```
class MyCorpus(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.table = AwesomeDataStructure()

    def insert(self):
        self.table.push_back(1)

    def find(self, needle):
        return self.table.find(needle)
```

I would like to expose the above class to my api.

I can create only one instance of that class (memory limit).

So I need to be able to instantiate this class before the server starts.
And my threads should be able to access it.

I also need some locking mechanism(conccurrent inserts are not supported).

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any global variable is shared between threads in Python, so this part is really easy: "... create only one instance of that class ... before the server starts ... threads should be able to access it":

```
corpus = MyCorpus()  # in global scope in any module
```

Done! Then import the instance from anywhere and call your class' methods:

```
from mydata import corpus

corpus.do_stuff()
```

No need for ZCA, plain pythonic Python  :)

*(the general approach of keeping something large and very database-like within the webserver process feels quite suspicious though, I hope you know what you're doing. I mean - persistence? locking? sharing data between multiple processes? Redis, MongoDB and 1001 other database products have those problems solved)*

Comment: it's a datastructure allowing fast fuzzy searches.
A DBMS is not an option here, except if i implement some C functions in the dbms. something that I am considering.

Comment: Process wide globals are a bit against the Pyramid way. It complicates testing and hinders having multiple apps run by single process. That's why configurable application wide "global" is preferred. Pyramid even (mostly) ditched thread locals for these reasons.

Comment: global variables? no, that's bad choice

Answer (score 6):

Add an instance of your class to the global [application registry](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/registry.html) during your [Pyramid application's configuration](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/configuration.html#configuration-narr):

```
config.registry.mycorpus = MyCorpus()
```

and later, for example in your view code, access it through a request:

```
request.registry.mycorpus
```

You could also register it as a utility with [Zope Component Architecture](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/zca.html) using `registry.registerUtility`, but you'd need to define what interface `MyCorpus` provides etc., which is a good thing in the long run. Either way having a singleton instance as part of the registry makes testing your application easier; just create a configuration with a mock corpus.

Any locking should be handled by the instance itself:

```
from threading import Lock

class MyCorpus(object):

    def __init__(self, Lock=Lock):
        self.table = AwesomeDataStructure()
        self.lock = Lock()

    ...

    def insert(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.table.push_back(1)
```

Comment: by doing the above only one memory copy exists?

Comment: That's the point of a global registry. Note that in pyramid the registry is global to the application, compared to how zope handles ZCA, which is global to process. That is if you deside to go the utility function route.

Comment: new to pyramid, so when doing:
```
 import waitress
    from config import service_config as config
    return waitress.create_server(app, host=config.bind_to, port=config.port, threads=config.frontend_threads)
````
it starts 1 app with multiple threads?
what happens in that case?

Comment: It starts 1 application that has 1 registry in which there's 1 instance of `MyCorpus`.